# Wordpress javascript navigation -- trying to add class to child-item when clicked on

Tags: javascript, wordpress, nav

I have a [mostly] working Nav Menu using Wordpress.
The Top Level menu-items work as intended and open the sub menu.

However when I try to add code to make the child-sub-menu have a specific class, so the sub-menu is shown, it breaks the upper level nav, and doesn't apply the class to the code as intended.

Working Top level code, no child sub-menu code added

- https://jsfiddle.net/szLmqvkn/

Non working (With Child Sub-Menu Code)

- https://jsfiddle.net/jqkwnpv1/2/

Any help would be appreciated.

Code for script

```
    window.onload = function(){
const toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item");
const submenu = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu");
const subitems = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item");

/* Toggle mobile menu */
function toggleMenu() {
  if (menu.classList.contains("active")) {
    menu.classList.remove("active");
    toggle.querySelector("a").innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-bars'></i>";
  } else {
   menu.classList.add("active");
    toggle.querySelector("a").innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-times'></i>";
  }
}
  

/* Activate Submenu */
function toggleItem() {
  if (this.classList.contains("sub-menu-active")) {
    this.classList.remove("sub-menu-active");
  } else if (menu.querySelector(".sub-menu-active")) {
    menu.querySelector(".sub-menu-active").classList.remove("sub-menu-active");
    this.classList.add("sub-menu-active");
  } else {
    this.classList.add("sub-menu-active");
  }
}
  
  

/* Close Submenu From Anywhere */
function closeSubmenu(e) {
  let isClickInside = menu.contains(e.target);

  if (!isClickInside && menu.querySelector(".sub-menu-active")) {
    menu.querySelector(".sub-menu-active").classList.remove("sub-menu-active");
  }
}
/* Event Listeners */
toggle.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu, false);
for (let item of items) {
  if (item.querySelector(".sub-menu")) {
    item.addEventListener("click", toggleItem, false);
  }
  item.addEventListener("keypress", toggleItem, false);
}
document.addEventListener("click", closeSubmenu, false);}





/*-----------------------------------*/


/*here is where i start having problems*/


/*-----------------------------------*/

 function toggleSubMenu() {
  if (submenu.classList.contains("active")) {
    submenu.classList.remove("active");
    } else {
   submenu.classList.add("active");

  }
} 



/* Activate Submenu */
function toggleChildItem() {
  if (this.classList.contains("child-menu-active")) {
    this.classList.remove("child-menu-active");
  } else if (menu.querySelector(".child-menu-active")) {
    menu.querySelector(".child-menu-active").classList.remove("child-menu-active");
    this.classList.add("child-menu-active");
  } else {
    this.classList.add("child-menu-active");
  }
}


/* Close Submenu From Anywhere */
function closeChildmenu(e) {
  let isClickInside = submenu.contains(e.target);

  if (!isClickInside && submenu.querySelector(".child-menu-active")) {
    submenu.querySelector(".child-menu-active").classList.remove("child-menu-active");
  }
}


/* Event Listeners */
toggle.addEventListener("click", toggleChildMenu, false);
for (let item of items) {
  if (item.querySelector(".child-menu-active")) {
    item.addEventListener("click", toggleChildItem, false);
  }
  item.addEventListener("keypress", toggleChildItem, false);
}
document.addEventListener("click", closeChildmenu, false);}
```

Comment: do you want like this https://jsfiddle.net/ao5snbh6/?

Comment: I was trying to keep it click based rather than hover to expand it